# Mysql sub query issues

Tags: mysql, subquery

I have a table where I record a number of values:

- `channel`, `cnam` (both varchar)
- `calldate` (date/time)
- `billsec` (integer)
- `disposition` (varchar - either 'ANSWERED' or 'NO ANSWER' or 'BUSY')

I need to report on the total number of records and billsec (which is a number of seconds) for certain `cnam`s, along with a breakdown of billsec by disposition, and the average duration.

I have a query that lets me select the correct set of rows to be reported on:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(channel,1, LOCATE("-",channel, LENGTH(channel)-8)-1) AS 
chan1,cnam,billsec,disposition 
FROM asteriskcdrdb.cdr
WHERE calldate >= '2017-12-08 00:00:00' AND calldate <= '2017-12-08 
23:59:59' AND (duration-billsec) >=0
HAVING chan1  LIKE 'SIP/3%' or chan1 IN ('SIP/2000','SIP/2016','SIP/2046')
ORDER BY chan1 asc
```

This returns results like the following:

```
chanl     | cnam     | billsec  | disposition
----------+----------+----------+----------------
SIP/2000  | foo      |    180   |  ANSWERED
SIP/2000  | foo      |     30   |  NO ANSWER
SIP/2000  | foo      |     60   |  ANSWERED
SIP/3010  | foo foo  |     2    |  BUSY
SIP/3010  | foo foo  |     3    |  BUSY
SIP/3010  | foo foo  |    240   |  ANSWERED
SIP/3020  | foo2     |     30   |  ANSWERED
SIP/3020  | foo2     |    180   |  ANSWERED
SIP/3020  | foo2     |     10   |  NO ANSWER
...
```

I have the start for how the query for my final results would go:

```
SELECT cnam,
       sum(disposition) as TOTAL,
       sum(disposition where disposition = 'ANSWERED') as COMPLETED,
       sum(disposition where disposition = 'NO ANSWER' OR case when 
       disposition = 'BUSY' then 1 else 0 end) as MISSED,
       SEC_TO_TIME(sum(billsec)) as 'Total DURATION',
       SEC_TO_TIME(avg(billsec)) as 'AVG DURATION'
```

My final results should look like this:

```
CNAM    | TOTAL | COMPLETED | MISSED | Total DURATION | AVG DURATION
--------+-------+-----------+--------+----------------+---------------
foo     |    3  |         3 |      1 |           1:30 |         0:32
foo foo |    3  |         3 |      2 |          03:05 |         1:02
foo2    |    3  |         2 |      1 |          03:34 |         1:12
```

I even know I can use a subquery to combine all this together. What I can't quite figure out is *how* to do that, given all the stuff that's in my initial query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the DDL and sample (raw) data, and not sure how you go from the first result set having all `cnam = "foo foo"` to the second result set having `CNAM = "foo" or "foo2"` ...

You could start with something like ...

```
select cnam,
       count(disposition) as TOTAL,
       sum(case when disposition = 'ANSWERED' then 1 else 0 end) as COMPLETED,
       sum(case when disposition = 'NO ANSWER' then 1 when disposition = 'BUSY' then 1 else 0 end) as MISSED,
       SEC_TO_TIME(sum(billsec)) as "Total DURATION",
       SEC_TO_TIME(avg(billsec)) as "AVG DURATION"

from   (SELECT SUBSTRING(channel,1, LOCATE("-",channel, LENGTH(channel)-8)-1) AS chan1,
               cnam,
               duration,
               disposition 

        FROM   asteriskcdrdb.cdr

        WHERE  calldate >= '2017-12-08 00:00:00' 
        AND    calldate <= '2017-12-08 23:59:59' 
        AND    (duration-billsec) >=0
        HAVING chan1 LIKE 'SIP/3%' 
            or chan1 IN ('SIP/2000','SIP/2016','SIP/2046')
       ) dt

group by cnam
order by cnam asc
```

... keep in mind that I'm not 100% sure of your logic (eg, should total/avg duration be based only on `COMPLETED` data?) so I mostly cut-n-pasted what you had originally.

---

OK, thinking about this a bit more ...

The derived table isn't really doing anything other than filtering out rows from the base table, which means the derived table could be eliminated.

One possible flattening of the query (using RDFozz's modified WHERE clause):

```
select cnam,
       count(disposition) as TOTAL,
       sum(case when disposition = 'ANSWERED'  then 1 else 0 end) as COMPLETED,
       sum(case when disposition = 'NO ANSWER' then 1 when disposition = 'BUSY' then 1 else 0 end) as MISSED,
       SEC_TO_TIME(sum(billsec)) as "Total DURATION",
       SEC_TO_TIME(avg(billsec)) as "AVG DURATION"

FROM   asteriskcdrdb.cdr

WHERE  calldate >= '2017-12-08 00:00:00' 
AND    calldate <= '2017-12-08 23:59:59' 
AND    (duration-billsec) >=0
AND    (   channel LIKE 'SIP/3%' 
        OR channel LIKE 'SIP/2000-%' 
        OR channel LIKE 'SIP/2016-%' 
        OR channel LIKE 'SIP/2046-%')

group by cnam
order by cnam asc
```

Comment: I updated the data up top. with a more clear explanation. I have tried to run this query and there are some errors. so i am working through them atm.

Comment: updated the query to fix a few typos I made while cutting-n-pasting

Comment: That sort of worked. The name, Total DURATION, AVG DURATION are producing results. The TOTAL,COMPLETED,MISSED are all coming up as 0's.

Comment: ahh, yeah, looking a bit more closely at your logic ... for `TOTAL` you need to use `count(*)`, and for the other 2 counters need to sum up 1's and 0's; have updated the query (again), see if that does it

Comment: @dreedy - FYI: the intent of the `HAVING` clause is to test aggregate values that can't be checked in the `WHERE` clause (because they can't be calculated until after the `WHERE` clause has been used to select the basic row set). As a side-effect, you may be able to use it to perform checks on aliased values (the column names you assign in the query itself, like `chanl`). However, most queries are more efficient if only aggregates are checked in the `HAVING` clause (so you don't do a bunch of calculations only to throw them out later). ...

Comment: ... In this case, it's pretty easy to move this check out of `HAVING` and into `WHERE`: `AND ( channel LIKE 'SIP/3%' OR channel LIKE 'SIP/2000-%' OR channel LIKE 'SIP/2016-%' OR channel LIKE 'SIP/2046-%')` would replace the `HAVING` clause. `chanl` is the start of `channel`, and I believe it would have to start with one of the four specified values to give you the values you're checking `chanl` for.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have changed the chanl to channel and removed the having to an addition to the where clause. I will try some more variation to see about the timing of the query. so far the original query with the having runs far quicker than in an altered state. almost a 100 times the speed of the altered state. This will be interesting to see what else can be done to optimize the query.

Comment: what do you mean by 'altered state' ... are you talking about the answer/query with a derived table?  looking at this a bit more ... since you're not using `chan1` in the top-level portion of the query, this means the derived table is basically just eliminating rows from the base table soooo, you could probably collapse/flatten this query (to eliminate the derived table) and see if that improves performance (though I'd expect mysql would be doing this behind the scenes any way ... or is that an unwise assumption to make with mysql?)

Comment: updated answer with a second/flattened query that eliminates the derived table; don't know if that'll help with the previously mentioned performance issues ...

Comment: Sorry for any delay. I have tried both and the performance of the second one now matches the first query. I will need to update some of the code as there were some errors on my part and want to give everyone a full explanation of all of it.

Comment: I have update a few things on the query that i have been going through a cleaning up with my testing.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong syntax; you want:

```
COUNT(*) AS 'Total'
SUM(m.disposition = 'ANSWERED') AS 'Completed'
```

(Anyway, a spelling error: `dispostion`.)

Recommend changing

```
WHERE calldate >= '2017-12-08 00:00:00'
  AND calldate <= '2017-12-08 23:59:59'
```

to

```
WHERE calldate >= '2017-12-08'
  AND calldate  < '2017-12-08' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Rather than having to do the `SUBSTRING...`, consider splitting the data as you insert it into the table.

I don't know what you are doing with 2 `SELECTs`, so I can't advise there.  You do not have a "subquery" that I can see.

Comment: Thanks for getting back with me. I have altered the original statement so that i make a little more. I was originally thinking it needed to be lined up as a sub query. but i am just drawing a blank to how to come to a final output.